# Store l3prop in l3seq

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3prop, l3seq

In a `.sty` file, I defined the following:

```tex
\seq_new:N \g__test_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \TestAdd {m}
  {
    \prop_clear_new:N \l__test_prop
    \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__test_prop
      {
        key1 = {#1},
        % other keys omitted
      }
    \seq_gpush:Nn \g__test_seq
      { \l__test_prop }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TestPrintAll {}
{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g__test_seq
    {
      \tl_clear_new:N \l__key_tl
      \par \prop_get:NnNTF {##1} {key1} \l__key_tl
        { \l__key_tl }
        { fallback }
    }
}
```

Then, in my document, I use them as follows:

```
\TestAdd{a}
\TestAdd{b}

\TestPrintAll{}
```

However, `pdflatex` outputs `b` twice, and I would like it to output `a` and then `b`.

I tried to use `\seq_gpush:NV` in `\TestAdd`, but `pdflatex` produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                A property list was misused.
```

Is there a way to store `prop`s inside a `seq` and then iterate over them?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are actually trying to achieve? As far as I can tell, "storing a property list in a sequence" has some of a logical problem in it.

Comment: I have a list of geographical places with multiple properties (some of them are optional) (location, name, some other attributes). I want to store them in a list in the preamble of my document, and then display them in multiple places in the document.

Comment: In this case, why don't you use one of the property list mapping functions directly?

Comment: Besides, I also don't understand how you expect to populate a property list with `\TestAdd` when you give it a single element/argument as you do. Are `a` and `b` in your example supposed to be the keys of your property list?

Comment: I think I don't understand what you mean by "property list mapping functions". `\prop_map_(inline|function)`?
If so, I don't really know how to do anything from that. I think I didn't explain my problem well enough. I want to store something like this (not LaTeX, but the idea is the same):

`[ { "name": "Place #1", "location": "Poland", "color": "blue" }, { "name": "Place #2", "location": "Italia", "owner": "John" }, ]`
I would like to add new places using `\TestAdd` and display them using `\TestPrintAll`.

Comment: @Vary does my answer satisfy your needs?

Comment: Ah! You are thinking a "sequence of property lists"! I guess Skillmon is on the right track, you are certainly well assisted there.  ;-)

Comment: It seems perfect. Thank you to both of you. I'll accept your answer @Skillmon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require implementation details, so is most likely not the "right" approach.

Better would be to store the input as `key=value` inside the `seq`, and use that. This way you don't use any implementation details but only documented interfaces:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g__Vary_test_seq
\prop_new:N \l__Vary_test_prop
\tl_new:N \l__Vary_key_tl

\NewDocumentCommand \TestAdd {m}
  {
    \seq_gpush:Nn \g__Vary_test_seq
      {
        key1 = {#1},
        % other keys omitted
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TestPrintAll {}
{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g__Vary_test_seq
    {
      \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__Vary_test_prop {##1}
      \par \prop_get:NnNTF \l__Vary_test_prop {key1} \l__Vary_key_tl
        { \l__Vary_key_tl }
        { fallback }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\TestAdd{a}
\TestAdd{b}

\begin{document}
\TestPrintAll{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Skillmon, that's neat and "evil" as you say. But I'm willing to bet this is just an XY question, and the OP really just want to populate a property list and typeset it... In which case other remedies would be much better.

Comment: Oh, you edited. Forget about the comment.  ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs (I removed the evil code.) I think that OP wants to store a list of property lists, and that's what this answer implements...

Comment: Yes, we just did like two people walking in different directions in the sidewalk, and each tried to give way to the other, just ending up bumping in each other.  :-)